# jquery append() element click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two ul tags
[here is jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/IMunucA/2/edit)

and my script is

```
$("#to-do li").click(function(){
    alert("I'm to-do li");
    $(this).appendTo("#done");
});

$("#done li").on('click', function(){
    // this event is not fired
    alert("I'm done li");
    $(this).appendTo("#to-do");
});
```

and requirement is on click of "to-do li" , it should append to "done li" and Vice-versa.

first function is working fine as expected. But the second one is not fired at all. 
on click of "#done li", again first function is calling. 
please help on..

1)why ("#to-do li") event is firing on click of $("#done li").
2)how to achive this

Comment: typically, use event delegation, so see at Arun's answer. Some read: http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events

Comment: why negative mark? whats wrong with this question?

Comment: I think because this question is asked hundred times a week

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are dealing with dynamic element structure you need to make use of event delegation

```
$('#to-do').on('click', "li", function () {
    console.log("I'm to-do li");
    $(this).appendTo("#done");
});

$('#done').on('click', "li", function () {
    // this event is not fired
    console.log("I'm done li");
    $(this).appendTo("#to-do");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ee5b9/)

Comment: +1 hey arun thanks, its working. But whats wrong with my script? means why we need to go with $(document)?

Comment: It's because you initially attach the event based on the `ul` the item is in. So when the `li` gets moved, the event attached to it is still related to the previous `li`. This method means the attached event is based on the containing `ul`.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I would change the selector to `$('#to-do').on('click', 'li', fn)` for better performance